# Revoke Privileges in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm  currently dealing with some `GRANT` options using Oracle Database Express Edition 11g. Consider the following small code example where some users grant some privileges to other users:

```
-- User A
GRANT Select, Insert, Update, Delete ON T TO B,C WITH GRANT OPTION ;
-- User B
GRANT Select ON T TO C WITH GRANT OPTION ;
GRANT Insert ON T TO C ;
-- USer C
GRANT Select, Insert, Update ON T TO D ;
```

User A is the creator of Table T and performs the following `REVOKE` operation.

Now `REVOKE Update ON T FROM C` is performed. Since no constraint is specified, the `REVOKE` operation should either cancel, because otherwise there would be an abandoned `UPDATE` privilege at `D`, or delete the privileges of both `C` and `D`.

Now my question is: Is the `REVOKE` statement actually cancelled or removes both `C` and `D` privileges? Or in other words, is the result after executing that revoke statement that both `C` and `D` still have the `UPDATE` privilege or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who performs the REVOKE?

Comment: User A performs it. A is also the creator of T, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: The RESTRICT keyword is not valid syntax for the Oracle database.

Comment: You're right, this keywork does not exist in Oracle. I've updated the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Revoke object privilege**

If user has granted the privilege to other users or roles, then the database also revokes the privilege from those other users or roles.

---

The correct REVOKE statement is:

```
  REVOKE object_priv [(column1, column2..)] ON [schema.]object 
         FROM {user, | role, |PUBLIC} [CASCADE CONSTRAINTS] [FORCE]
```

There is no `RESTRICT` in Oracle. The `RESTRICT` exists in PostgresSQL, MariaDB, etc.

However I think your intended way is just `REVOKE Update ON T FROM C` executed from A user.
After that there is no any error and users C and D do NOT have privilege to update T.

Comment: You're absolutely right, there is no `RESTRICT` in Oracle. So you mean that the Oracle default behavior is `CASCADE`, right?

Comment: Yes, we can say `CASCADE` is default for `WITH  GRANT OPTION` grants... The other story is with granting system privileges `WITH ADMIN OPTION`. These ones will not be revoked.