# What kind of operations makes oracle to lose a grant?

Tags: oracle, sql-grant

I know that drop an object can cause to destroy a grant.
But what else can cause to lose a grant over an object?

Am asking that since I have to write some guidelines for the revs DB at work, I'd like to creae a list of operation where is necessary to also regenerate the grants for other schemas.

Comment: revoke dba from <user>

Answer (score 0):

If also the user that grant access revoked access

you can look at this Question for more info :
[Revoke Privileges in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288932/revoke-privileges-in-oracle)